# Optimizing expected sale price by dynamic programming

Tags: optimization

I would like to sell my computer to the highest bidder.  I have studied the market, and concluded that I am likely to receive three types of offers: an offer of \$200 dollars with probability $2/7$, an offer of \$300 dollars with probability $4/7$, and an offer of \$400 dollars with probability $1/7$.

I will advertise my computer for up to three consecutive days.  At the end of each of the three days, I will decide whether or not to accept the best offer made that day.

What is the optimum strategy for maximizing the expected sale price for my computer?  What is this expected sale price?

Comment: This is not clear.  How many offers can I expect in a day?  Is the number of offers itself probabilistic?  Are the various offers independent of each other?

Comment: @lulu  i dont know but i am thinking the 7 stands for weekly with those probailities

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  If I expect multiple independent offers then the probabilities should not sum to $1$ (as you might get all three types of offers, for example).

Comment: I suspect the probabilities are for the highest dollar bid received in a single day.

Comment: @hardmath  That's at least possible, but it's a bit of a stretch to get there from the wording.

Comment: @lulu:  The title mentioned (before I edited it) "dynamic programming", so that suggests (taken together with the wording "at the end of each of the three days, I will decide...") that the probabilities refer to events on each day independently.  Of course one needs to choose the best offer of any day when accepting an offer, if the expected sale price is to be maximized.

Comment: @hardmath u think u can help with these because i am kind of lost here

Comment: I'll write up a solution based on @hardmath 's interpretation.

Comment: What does the "dynamic programming" approach mean to you?  What if there were only one day of "advertising"?

Comment: @hardmath   dynamic programming for me is to get the best solution of any particular promlem .to maximize the sale price for this problem i would say

Comment: It is actually a specific approach to finding "the best solution", which I hope your classroom instruction will help you appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Using the interpretation of @hardmath, we may as well assume we only get one offer each day, with the stated probabilities.

Now, there's no point taking a $\$200$ offer prior to the last day (as you can't do worse by waiting to see the third offer).  On the other end, of course you should take a $\$400$ offer as soon as you get it, as you can't do better.  The only debate comes if you get a $\$300$ offer before the last day.

Case I.  suppose you have made it to day $2$ and get a $\$300$ offer.  Then you look at your odds. With probability $\frac 27$ you lose $\$100$. With probability $\frac 17$ you win $\$100$ otherwise you break even.  That's a bad bet...much greater chance of losing money than making any, so you should take the $\$300$.

Case II.  suppose you see a $\$300$ offer on day $1$.  What happens if you wait?  Well you win $\$100$ if you get a $\$400$ offer on day $2$ (probability $\frac 17$). If you get another $\$300$ (probability $\frac 47$) then (by our case I analysis) you break even.  If you only get a $\$200$ offer then you try again, at which point your expectation is $$\frac 27\times 200+\frac 47\times 300+\frac 17 \times 400=\$285$$   Putting all this together, the expected value of waiting is $$\frac 17 \times 400+\frac 47\times 300 +\frac 27\times 285=\$310$$

this is (ever so slightly!) greater than $\$300$ so in this case you ought to wait.

Comment: Nicely explained.  Note this essentially simultaneous [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719140/optimization-problem-using-probability-dynamic-programming), which suggests this was a class assignment.

Comment: @hardmath Ah, thanks.  Think I ought to delete my answer?

Comment: No I don't want you to waste my up-vote!  Seriously the OP will learn much from relating your calculation to the dynamic programming point of view.

Comment: @hardmath I'll leave it then (and thanks for the vote).

Comment: @lulu yea but i dont think this is how its done i gotta use probability dynamic programming

Comment: It is not difficult to translate my solution into the language of dynamic programming.  Just write out the decision tree!

Comment: @foley:  The pieces of the computation are all there for you now, needing only some rearrangement to produce a clear application of dynamic programming.

Comment: @hardmath ok thank you